# How does DS Register affect Instruction Pointer in Real Mode

Tags: assembly, gdb, qemu, bootloader

I have some code for a simple bootloader (boot.asm):

```
    BITS 16
start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax
    jmp $; infinite loop
.done:
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

I assemble it with "nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm"
I run it in qemu with "qemu boot.asm -s -S"

Now this bootloader gets loaded at address 0x7C00. Here is a disassembly of those instructions:

```
(gdb) x/10i 0x7c00
=> 0x7c00:  mov    $0x7c0,%ax
   0x7c03:  mov    %ax,%ds
   0x7c05:  jmp    0x7c05
   0x7c07:  ret    
   0x7c08:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c0a:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c0c:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
```

Here are the registers at the time:

```
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xaa55   43605
ecx            0x0  0
edx            0x80 128
ebx            0x0  0
esp            0x6efc   0x6efc
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x0  0
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x7c00   0x7c00
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x0  0
ss             0x0  0
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

Now I step past the following instruction:

```
(gdb) ni
[   0:7c03] => 0x7c03:  mov    %ax,%ds
```

When I print the code at 0x7c00 I see something unexpected:

```
(gdb) x/10i 0x7c00
   0x7c00:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c02:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c04:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c06:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c08:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
   0x7c0a:  add    %al,(%bx,%si)
```

Here are the registers:

```
(gdb) info registers
 eax            0x7c0   1984
 ecx            0x0 0
 edx            0x80    128
 ebx            0x0 0
 esp            0x6efc  0x6efc
 ebp            0x0 0x0
 esi            0x0 0
 edi            0x0 0
 eip            0x7c05  0x7c05
 eflags         0x202   [ IF ]
 cs             0x0 0
 ss             0x0 0
 ds             0x7c0   1984
 es             0x0 0
 fs             0x0 0
 gs             0x0 0
```

We never make it to the jmp instruction! I'm guessing this is because the segment register is changed (but CS is still 0). Does anyone have any reference material about why changing DS register seemingly changes the address of the next instruction to be executed?

Comment: Changing DS doesn't change the address of the next instruction executed. It's always CS:IP. What it appears to have changed is what `x/10i 0x7c00` displays. You're seeing the code at 07C0:7C00 instead of the code at 0000:7C00.

Comment: Interesting. If I step instruction, I will never go to the jmp code statement though, maybe this is a display issue as well though.

Comment: I'm surprised GDB works at all with 16-bit code. It might not be displaying the instruction correctly when single stepping or it might not be single stepping correctly.

Comment: Thanks Ross, I have added a few instructions to print a character and it works whether or not I modify the ds register. I will close this question

 mov ah, 0x0e
 mov al, 'A'
        int 0x10
 jmp $